# How to show custom taxonomy per post? WordPress REST API?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I want to display posts from WordPress REST API, it's a custom post type where I wanna display in my case :

I have single custom post type post from REST API, point is to get taxonomy term from REST, e.g.

```
...
"wp:term": [
      {

        "taxonomy": "examplestatus",

        "embeddable": true,

        "href": "domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/category?post=217"

      }

]
...
```

I can get an example term but I must create one new request to `"href"` part, it can be robust. How to solve in a different way? New field? Register one : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_field/

Thanks!

Comment: did you solve this? with `/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?post=903` I get "Sorry, you are not allowed to view terms for this post."  This works fine if the id belongs to a normal post type.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the "show_in_rest" argument is set to **true** in the custom taxonomy registration. If you are using a plugin, look in the settings of the custom taxonomy. If you have coded the registration yourself, look in that location (usually functions.php).